# Json response, how to decode characters with accent?

Tags: php, json, unicode

I am receiving Json response from a webservice so the character Ô turns into \u00d3

How can PETR\u00d3POLIS became PETRÓPOLIS ?

I am using PHP to query the database and return JSON.

After a research from  http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00d3/index.htm i know the character is Unicode Character 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH ACUTE' (U+00D3) .

Wich is the best way to translate these characters ?

Comment: How do you use this JSON? Do you output it to HTML?

Comment: for now i just output, just do not know how it will be used. I could filter this issue with javascript ? i just use : echo `json_encode($JsonElement);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unicode characters are just like escape characters - you can see them in JS string, but they will be displayed properly as a text.

```js
var o = {
  text: 'PETR\u00d3POLIS  \n\u00a5\u00a5\u00a5'
};

document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + o.text + "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below regex

```
$string = "u00d3";
echo $string = preg_replace('/u([\da-fA-F]{4})/', '&#x\1;', $string)
```

Comment: utf8_encode converts ISO-8859-1 text to UTF-8.  It doesn't help to solve this issue in any way.

Comment: It isn't a html entity. This is still a wrong answer, just delete it.